# Facebook Page link to Photos?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to link to the facebook photos tab of a Page via an iFrame loaded from a custom App (tab)? If I try to link to num?sk=photos, it gives me the "Go to Facebook.com" loaded in that iframe. I pretty much want a redirect.

Is that possible? Or does FB block link-ins like that?

Let me know,
Thanks!

Comment: have you set target = _top on your link?

Comment: Oh, that was easy. I don't use iframes much. Guess I should have looked harder. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using javascript to set  `window.top.location.href = url;`, but after reading Igy's comment, I think I'll be switching to `target = _top`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out facebook developer page.

You can use GRAPH API to access photos, photo albums, profile pictures unless any user has different privacy setting.

You might want to check out [GRAPH API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for that, I hope it might help you to get started.

Comment: The problem of linking to photos still applies when using the Graph API. the `target = _top` tip is still helpful there.